# CLOS: How to make a slot have an enforced type of vector of symbols?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clos

I'm trying to create a class that can store a vector of symbols in a slot in SBCL.  I cannot figure out how to set it up.

My best guess thus far has been

```
(defclass Individual ()
  ((discrete-decisions :type (vector symbol))))
```

This returns the following error:

```
keyword argument not a symbol:
(DISCRETE-DECISIONS :TYPE (VECTOR SYMBOL)).
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

Some experimenting has shown that changing the type to just `symbol` returns the same error.  I thought that `symbol` was a valid type in Common Lisp... am I mistaken?

How can I get this to work?

[EDIT]

The above problem I had was running SBCL 1.0.58 in the 09-22-2012 Slime build under Emacs 24.2.  When I run SBCL 1.0.58 from the command line, there is no problem.  This doesn't seem like an SBCL issue...

Comment: btw., in default safety settings SBCL will not check slot types

Comment: I'm using SBCL 1.0.58 on Windows 7.  Might this be a bug?

Comment: could be, you should consult the sbcl mailing list

Comment: The [spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcla.htm) says that the effect of storing values of another type in the slot is undefined. So it's not 'portable' to expect the type to be checked. An alternative is to leave the type unspecified and test yourself using [`check-type`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_check_.htm).

Answer (score 4):

You might consider defining an :after method on slot accessor/writer.  Also, the ultimate degree of control can be exercised by defining your own metaclass and customization of slot-value-using-class

Comment: Or use :before. For example, for the class cell with slot genome, we can ensure that the type of the object in the genome slot matches that specified in the class definition: `(defmethod (setf cell-genome) :before (new-value (object cell))
  (let ((sd-genome (slot-definition-for-cell-genome)))
    (assert (typep new-value (sb-mop:slot-definition-type sd-genome)))))`

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm probably too late, but you should wrap around your classe declaration with a optimization for safety. For example:

```
(locally (declare (optimize safety))
    (defclass test-class ()
      ((some-slot :type real :initarg :some-slot :accessor :test-some-slot))))
```