# CLOS: enforce slots have a specific type when initarg, slot-writer?

Tags: validation, types, common-lisp, assert, clos

How can I enforce slot's type in CLOS.

I know that `(locally (declare (optimize safety))) (defclass foo () ((num :type number...` could be answer, but I think it's not portable enough. (only with SBCL, not CLISP 2.49)

Or, should I implement those things? (for check each slots following specified `:type`s.)

1. defmethod `:after (setf SLOT)`.
2. defmethod `:after initialize-instance`.

Is there any simpler way to do that?

And, is there any "MOP" or metaclass something for hook "slot-updates"?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I think it's not the same question with [CLOS: How to make a slot have an enforced type of vector of symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556513/clos-how-to-make-a-slot-have-an-enforced-type-of-vector-of-symbols?lq=1), because I need more informations about that "metaclass" or `slot-value-with-class` things.

**EDIT**: I found `closer-mop` provides preferrable, portable-way.

```
CL-USER> (nth 0 (closer-mop:class-slots (find-class 'foo-class)))
CL-USER> (closer-mop:slot-definition-type *)
```

Comment: `(locally (declare (optimize safety)))` won't provide an answer.  An implementation can discard type declarations, so optimizing for safety won't guarantee a check.  If you absolutely want to guarantee that the value has a particular type, you're going to have to get into the methods for setting the slot's values.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Please read 'all of them'. I was question about "that" too. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and since you wrote (emphasis added) "I know that ... *could* be an answer, but I *think* it's not portable enough," I was commenting in support to your hypothesis.  I did read the whole question.

Comment: Actually, English is not my mother tongue, at all. I was misunderstood your intentions & nuance, sorry again. :-)

Comment: No worries,  and no harm done.  I think your other hypothesis (that you'll need to get into `:after` methods on the setting methods is probably correct.  You'll have to be careful about all the ways to set the value, though (e.g., setf slot-value).

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for something like a `*update-slot-hook*` auto'mize -or- macro'mize that. Actually, I'm not expecting something like that. but I think there should be other way to do, it's very primitive thing, a type-checking for instance's slot. I think.